# Forgot to put storyboard files into .gitignore

Tags: objective-c, git, ios5, version-control

I have seen a few questions similar to this around but could not figure out what I needed by them.

I set up a git repository for an iphone project I am working on. I forgot to put my storyboard related files into the .gitignore. I have now been working it for a long time and now realize my mistake.

Most posts about this say you need to go through and manually remove them from the repository and then add the storyboard files to .gitignore. Do I really have to go through and do:

rm ignoredfile1 ignoredfile2 etc...?

Isn't there some way to do all of this automatically (I believe they are all in the same directory)? I am not very familiar with the terminal so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: .storyboard files are source code files.  Why would you not want them under source control?  Just leave them be; Xcode has done the right thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rm --cached <files>` just as you would use a usual unix `rm` command.
This leaves the files where they are, but removes them from the repository.

Comment: More correctly, it removes them from being under source control.  The files previously committed are still in the repository, but new changes won't get committed.  If you want to remove the actual content of the files, it's a more advanced filter-branch operation.  However, if they're not consuming lots of space, there's no reason to worry with deleting the content.  Just `git rm --cached <files>` and proceed as normal.

Comment: @wadesworld yepp, you're right. They are still part of the previous commits, but won't show up in any further commit after the removal commit. That's what I apparently mislabled _removes them from the repository_ ;)